# trying to set up random backgroundcolors with eventlistener whilst hovering over grid-cells with js

Tags: javascript, random, background-color

this is my first question here - i'm learning alone.

So I set up a grid and it works kind of like the etch a sketch game, you can draw by hovering. It worked fine just for the black background, but I want to go further and have each cell change the background when hovering over it.

now it does not even paint it black anymore since I inserted the randomBgColor function.

this is the code:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  document.body.prepend(button);

  button.textContent = "press me to set grid size";
  const myGrid = document.querySelector("#myGrid");
  let customGrid = "";

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    customGrid = parseInt(prompt("insert a number between 0 & 100"));
    for (let i = 0; i < customGrid; i++) {
      const column = document.createElement("div");
      column.classList.add("column");
      myGrid.appendChild(column);
      for (let j = 0; j< customGrid; j++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.classList.add("cell");
        cell.classList.add("hover");
        column.appendChild(cell);
      }
      function randomBgColor() {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
        console.log(bgColor);
      }
      randomBgColor();

      const hover = document.querySelectorAll(".hover");
      hover.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
          element.style.backgroundColor = randomBgColor();
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I added the randomBgColor() function with googles' help and it returns numeric random values, but it does not change the color of each cell.

I expected it to change each cells color as I replaced the "black" at
element.style.backgroundColor = "black";

with

```
    element.style.backgroundColor = randomBgColor();
```

but it does not do anyhting, in fact it stopped working completely.

Console in devtools says nothing just random rgb number indications...

can someone help?

Comment: why does your code have `>` as the first character in every line? did you type that out painstakingly rather that copy/paste?

Comment: `randomBgColor` doesn't [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) anything, so `element.style.backgroundColor = randomBgColor();` is like doing `element.style.backgroundColor = undefined`

Comment: hi @JaromandaX that was a formatting mistake trying to make it look like code in the question. I actually now inserted this part

"const hover = document.querySelectorAll(".hover");
    hover.forEach((element) => {
     element.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        element.style.backgroundColor = randomBgColor();
        });
    });"

into the randomBgColor function and now it changes it randomly to one color, but not every grid to a different one..

Comment: can you provide us with a playground version so we can debug  ? like stackover flow or jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mariamneu/kghL732s/51/ yes please

Comment: got it actually https://jsfiddle.net/mariamneu/kghL732s/53/

Comment: `that was a formatting mistake` - ahh, how can we help if you don't post code you want help with

Comment: noo, the formatting mistake was just the > problem you mentioned in your first comment. I had a question about the code but I got it myself